# WebSite Navigation design

Tags: web, navigation

I'm designing a blog site and is confused about position of navigation pane on my site. Please suggest wheather I should go with design having navigation panel on top of page, on left sidebar or on right sidebar? Which one is preferred?

Can you give some examples supporting your answers?

Comment: You might want to ask the people over at http://doctype.com/ .  This site is about programming issues/questions.

Comment: This is very subjective. There is no real evidence to say one is better than the other. It all depends on how it fits within the context of your overall site. If you stick with xhtml/css best practices I can't see much why it would matter.

Comment: Not enough details. For a blog you might not even need any navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are just some points: put it on the top. The disadvantage is, that most people have widescreen monitors, so they have to scroll more. If the navigation is on the right, people with smaller monitors can't see the navigation without scrolling. If you put it on the left, they maybe have to scroll to the content. Always think of the smaller monitors, then there should be no problems :)